# Saving EPOCH time value in user define column in influxDB

Tags: epoch, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB and want to write Epoch time values  in user define column as shown below in v1 field.

```
cpu_load,host=server01,core=0 value=0.45,v1=1437171724
cpu_load,host=server01,core=0 value=0.45,v1=1437171725
```

Now, how can i query this column just like i can query regular time based column

```
select * from cpu_load where v1 > '2016-08-31 00:42:24.000'
```

This query is not working, however if i switch v1 with time column it works just fine.

```
select * from cpu_load where time > '2016-08-31 00:42:24.000'
```

Wondering how can i use user define time/column value in InfluxDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfluxDB only supports field types of string, integer, float, and boolean.

The `time` column is a special case. Even though it is stored as an integer under the hood, only the `time` field can be filtered with time based constraints.

There is a longstanding [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4113) to allow comparison of fields to `time`.

In the meantime, the raw integer Epoch time value can be used to set a constraint on the `v1` field. E.g.

```
select * from "cpu_load" where "v1" > 1472604144000
```